# Conditions for the value of a determinant to be zero

Tags: matrices, determinant

The theory states that the value of a determinant will be zero if it contains a row or column full of zeroes or if it has two identical rows or two rows proportional to each other.

> Similarly, can we say that the value of the determinant is zero only if it satisfies the above mentioned conditions?

Could someone please explain me this?

Comment: No. The determinant will also be zero if one row is a linear combination of other rows. That is what is essential: the determinant is nonzero if and only if the rows (equivalently, columns) are linearly independent.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody can explain it since it is not true. For instance,$$\begin{vmatrix}0&1&1\\1&0&1\\1&1&2\end{vmatrix}=0,$$in spite of the fact that *none* of the conditions that you mentioned hold. The general rule is: a determinant is $0$ if and only if some row is a linear combination of the other rows (and, of course, this is also equivalent to the assertion that some column is a linear combination of the other columns).

Answer (score 1):

At first, some definitions:

> A function $f\colon X^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is multilinear when is linear respect all their variables.

and other

> A function $f\colon X^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is alternating when:
>    $$ f(x_1,\ldots,x_i,\ldots,x_j,\ldots,x_n)=-f(x_1,\ldots,x_j,\ldots,x_i,\ldots,x_n) $$

At least

> A determinant function $f\colon X^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is a multilinear alternating function.

So if we have $x_i=x_k$ for some $i,k\leq n$:

$$ f(x_1,\ldots,x_i,\ldots,x_k,\ldots,x_n)=-f(x_1,\ldots,x_k,\ldots,x_i,\ldots,x_n) $$
$$ =-f(x_1,\ldots,x_i,\ldots,x_k,\ldots,x_n) \mbox{ since }x_i=x_k$$
so $$f(x)=-f(x) \Leftrightarrow f(x)=0, \mbox{ where } x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$$
So, If $x$ has two equal elements, $f(x)=0$.

If $x$ has some $0$: 
$$f(x_1,\ldots,0,\ldots,x_n)=f(x_1,\ldots,0+0,\ldots,x_n)$$
$$f(x_1,\ldots,0,\ldots,x_n)=f(x_1,\ldots,0,\ldots,x_n)+f(x_1,\ldots,0,\ldots,x_n)\mbox{ since } f \mbox{ is linear }$$
$$f(x)=f(x)+f(x)$$
$$f(x)=0$$